# How do I use Twine with my Xcode Project?

Tags: objective-c, localization

[Twine](https://github.com/mobiata/twine) looks great, but the documentation is a bit lacking, and there is no sample iOS project. I'm wondering how I would incorporate this tool into my project.

Specifically:

1. Is it recommended that my keys be arbitrary codes (e.g. `path_not_found_error`) or English words/sentences as Apple recommends (e.g. `Unable to find path`). [The article that introduces Twine](https://www.mobiata.com/blog/2012/02/08/twine-string-management-ios-mac-os-x) mentions how English words/sentences fall short when a single word could mean two different things (e.g. list as noun vs. a verb), but then also mentions the drawbacks of using keys: if you forget to include one, the user will see your key name (`path_not_found_error`) rather than the English counterpart (`Unable to find path`).
2. Say I'm writing code and I want to include a new string. What are the steps in order to do so? When following Apple's recommendation, I can simply type `NSLocalizedString(@"Sample text", nil)`, and I am done. What is the process in order to get it working with Twine?
3. In [their examples](https://github.com/mobiata/twine), they show categories such as `[[General]]` and `[[Errors]]`. How do I categorize a string?
4. In [their examples](https://github.com/mobiata/twine), they show tags. what exactly are these, and how would I use them?

Answer (score 2):

#### To generate the first version of `strings.txt`:

1. Generate `Localizable.strings` from all the `NSLocalizedString` macros in your code.

   `find . -name \*.m | xargs genstrings -o /tmp`
2. It is recommended to save this in `Resources/Locales/en.lproj/Localizable.strings`
3. Create the initial, empty strings.txt file:

   `touch strings.txt`
4. Populate it with the contents of `Localizable.strings`:

   `twine consume-all-string-files strings.txt Resources/Locales --developer-language en --consume-all --consume-comments`

It seems that after doing this once, it's recommended that you manually modify the `strings.txt` file going forward.

#### To create a new string in your code:

1. Type in the string you want to use, for example:

   `NSString *prompt = NSLocalizableString(@"prompt_user_name", nil);`
2. Manually add the key/value to the `strings.txt` file, optionally placing them in a category:

   `[prompt_user_name]
       en = Please enter in a user name`
3. Now when you build the project, it will generate `Localizable.strings` and when you run the app you will see the correct string. (Assuming you followed the [Twine and Your Build Process](https://github.com/mobiata/twine#twine-and-your-build-process) steps.)

Answer (score 0):

> 3. In their examples, they show categories such as [[General]] and [[Errors]]. How do I categorize a string?

Actually, there is no way to add sections automatically, checked their master and there is no section parser in apple strings formatter. So I suppose that the only way is to do it manually.

> 4. In their examples, they show tags. what exactly are these, and how would I use them?

This works when you have app on multiple platforms. For example you can add tags iOS and Android and then generate resources based on your tag for particular platform.